# JS bookmarklet issue: Code works in console, fails in bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, wordpress, bookmarklet

Using a JS bookmarklet to set a custom field in the Wordpress Edit Post screen. The following code works well when I copy/paste it into the console (latest Chrome stable):

```
document.getElementById('metakeyselect').value = "foo";
document.getElementById('metavalue').value = "bar";
document.getElementById('meta-add-submit').click();
```

Works without a hitch; I jut paste this into the console, and a new custom var is added to the post (I have "foo" as a var name in WP already).

In bookmarklet form, this same code looks like this:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('metakeyselect').value = "foo";document.getElementById('metavalue').value = "bar";document.getElementById('meta-add-submit').click();
```

And it fails: When I click it, the Name and Value boxes are filled in, but nothing gets submitted. The console shows the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null
```

Any idea why? Same exact code, same browser, same page.

Comment: can you send a link to the page? or past its code?

Comment: No, it was not the same DOM as `document.getElementById('meta-add-submit')` returned `null` - the element did not exist. Check it in your DOM inspector, it might have been dynamically (and conditionally) inserted by JS

Comment: The page is just the default Edit Post page in WordPress. And re the DOM: It was already loaded when I clicked the bookmarklet, so why is it not the same DOM?

Comment: I have the same issue, with Chrome 25.0.1364.152. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. When it works, it works permanently. After browser restart, it might work or not. If it fails, it fails permanently... until next browser restart. I tried with getElementById() and with getElementyByName(), both return null/empty, when it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try adding a `document.close();` command before the `document.getElementById('meta-add-submit').click();`  command? I've seen sporadic failures on certain pages/browsers attempting to call a `click()` method after altering the DOM without closing the document.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and am quite sure that's what causes your code to break too.
My minimal example would be the following code on this website (should work afor the entire stackoverflow.com domain):

```
document.getElementsByName("q")[0].value="foo";
```

This should write "foo" to the search field (that has no id but is the only element with the name "q"). Both web console and bookmarklet will set the value as expected but the bookmarklet will also change the page to an empty header and a body containing only the word "foo" after a short delay. Assuming that this is not a random bug that only applies to me, the reason for the thrown exception in your example is that the bookmarklet sets the value "foo", then "bar" but changes the content of the web page to "foo", then "bar" before your last line terminates.

Unfortunately I don't know the reason for this behaviour (I found this question looking for that exact information) but that is what most likely causes the TypeError in your excample.

It is possible that the same code runs without any problems when used in a Greasemonkey script (e.g. as the onclick script of a button you added using Greasemonkey).

[Edit:] Apparently, if a bookmarklet evaluates to anything other than `undefined`, the inner html of the website is replaced by a string representation of that value. To make sure that the bookmarklet evaluates to `undefined`, you can just type `undefined` as the last line outside of any condition block. unfortunately that means it is less likely that my assumption toward OP's error is correct but at least future visitors still might find this information usefull.

Comment: I, too, came here looking for an explanation for this exact behavior. Can you post the source of the explanation you found?

Comment: @jdunk I am not sure what you mean. I found this question here looking for answers and stayed to share what I knew so far.

Comment: hajef You found this explanation somewhere: "if a bookmarklet evaluates to anything other than undefined, the inner html of the website is replaced by a string representation of that value". I'm just asking where, because I looked for any official/authoritative source at all and couldn't find any.

Comment: Like an RFC or MDN docs or *something*. Best I could find was a personal webpage someone had written.

Comment: @jdunk 

It's been a long time but I think that this was just the result of my own analysis/troubleshooting/testing. As soon as there was a returned value, that value became the new source code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code you use in console works ok.

It seems like the method you turn console code into a bookmarklet is what might result into an error.

The basic **IIFE-construction**, i.e. Immediately Invoked Function Expression, looks like this:

```
javascript:(function () {
    /*code here*/
})();
```

Therefore, the code that is supposed to work might be this.

```
javascript:(function () {
    document.getElementById('metakeyselect').value = "foo";
    document.getElementById('metavalue').value = "bar";
    document.getElementById('meta-add-submit').click();
})();
```

Does it solve your problem?